# Add multi-line/autowrap to imagestring in PHP

Tags: php, string, textarea, word-wrap

I have a code which is working for me (see below),

But the textarea does not word-wrap, however I ask it nicely. I tried all I can find online, but not knowing PHP properly, it is a bit hard. I think I tried whatever there is for 'imagestring'. This piece of imagestring is stubborn, indeed.
I thought I will trick it with css, nada. js, nada.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_name);  
        header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");

        $string = $_POST['caption'];
        $font = 12;
        $width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
        $height = imagefontheight($font);
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
        $x = imagesx($im) - $width;
        $y = imagesy($im) - $height;
        $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);
        imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y, $string, $textColor);
        $a = imagejpeg($im);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Custom Text to Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="file" name="image"> 
                  <textarea name="caption" rows="10" cols="62" style="white-space: pre- 
                  line;" wrap="hard">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t think `imagestring` cares for newline characters, so even if you could get your textarea to do a “hard wrap”, you would still need to loop over the lines on the server side, and call `imagestring` for each single line … The user comments for that function in the manual have several approaches for automatic wrapping, so try those.

Comment: going over that manual back and forth...